# How can certain things be omitted from the page source

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am writing a program that automatically start up a web browser to a song of choice, so in order to do this my program is using an httwebrequest/response to

- get the source code of a webpage that contains a link to the audio source page
- search through that website source code and find the audio source website
- open up chrome the the specified webpage, so i can listen to the song.

I am using project.com as my audio source, and I do not plan on using another site such as youtube

The problem I am having, is that, while I can see a link to the audio source website when i load the initial website in chrome, the page source does not contain it. For instance, this [website](http://www.playlist.com/searchbeta/tracks?category=Homepage-logged_out&action=ClickSubmitSearch#r%20u%20mine/all/1) which
has a link to the audio source `http://pl.st/s/1709472017` where you can actually see on the initial website, but when I look at the page source using chrome, then I cannot find this audio source link.

If I right click on the audio source textbox and select inspect element, then I can see this:

```
<input class="copy-song-link" 
   type="textbox" 
   value="http://pl.st/s/1709472017" 
   name="url" 
   onclick="javascript:select();" title="Copy and share this song URL">
```

so this link is clearly located somewhere. My questions are these

- why/how is this link not in the source page, but i can see when i look at the website through chrome
- how come chrome's "inspect element" can find this url, while the page source does not include it.
- How does the inspect element differ from looking at the source code?

I am pretty new to http communication so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use the plugin Firebug for Firefox for situations like this. It will allow you to use the ["Net" tab](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) to inspect all subsequent requests (often Ajax) that occur while the page is loading.

In your case it appears an Ajax request was collecting the data that is being used to generate the link that you want to pull out. This data appears in JSON and JavaScript is likely generating the links on the client side from the JSON. Take a look at this link
http://www3.playlist.com/async/searchbeta/tracks?searchfor=r%20u%20mine

The linkid used to generate the link is in the first part of the response ...PPL.search.trackdata = [{"linkid":1709472017...